# Go: Process multi-line command output and parse

Tags: regex, go, ntp

I am trying to extract information from a command line utility, in this case the linux ntpq -c rv command.

Output:

```
associd=0 status=0638 leap_none, sync_ntp, 3 events, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Jul 22 17:30:51 UTC 2016 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64", leap=00, stratum=2,
precision=-22, rootdelay=25.435, rootdisp=49.398, 
refid=8.8.8.8,
reftime=dd64d70e.3edbe503  Thu, Sep 14 2017 12:23:10.245,
clock=dd64dbaa.ded8fa8e  Thu, Sep 14 2017 12:42:50.870, peer=51954,
tc=10, mintc=3, offset=1.941, frequency=3.236, sys_jitter=0.869,
clk_jitter=0.413, clk_wander=0.068
```

What i need out of this is: stratum and offset.

I have built this piece of code:

```
if Exists("/usr/bin/ntpq") {
  cmd := exec.Command("ntpq","-c rv")
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Printf("out %s\n", scanner.Text())
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error starting Cmd", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error waiting for Cmd", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I am able to get the output from the command, line by line but i am unsure on how to extract only the information i want.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I have a `awk` bash script I can share which gives the offset if that's of any use?

Comment: thank you, my preference is in Go :)

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you just read the output synchronously, there's no reason for the concurrency here. There's not really any reason for scanning the lines either as the parsing is the same, just read the output as a whole.

Comment: Easy: `\bstratum:(\d+)` and `\boffset:([\d.]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Regular Expression](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) to get the data and [parse it](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) into int, and float values.

> https://play.golang.org/p/vDx8dw4Mpo

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // Expected output
    output := `associd=0 status=0638 leap_none, sync_ntp, 3 events, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Jul 22 17:30:51 UTC 2016 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64", leap=00, stratum=2,
precision=-22, rootdelay=25.435, rootdisp=49.398, 
refid=8.8.8.8,
reftime=dd64d70e.3edbe503  Thu, Sep 14 2017 12:23:10.245,
clock=dd64dbaa.ded8fa8e  Thu, Sep 14 2017 12:42:50.870, peer=51954,
tc=10, mintc=3, offset=1.941, frequency=3.236, sys_jitter=0.869,
clk_jitter=0.413, clk_wander=0.068`

    // Try to find stratum
    match :=  regexp.MustCompile("stratum=(\\d+),").FindStringSubmatch(output)
    stratum := 0
    if (match != nil) {
        if i, err := strconv.Atoi(match[1]); err == nil {
            stratum = i
        }
    }

    // Try to find offset
    match =  regexp.MustCompile("offset=(\\d+\\.\\d+),").FindStringSubmatch(output)
    offset := 0.0
    if (match != nil) {
        if f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(match[1], 64); err == nil {
            offset = f
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(stratum)
    fmt.Println(offset)
}
```